How do I create the input argument "Object" for read_with_array_buffer_view(&obj)?
In this case I am trying to read a small utf8 text file ( < 4k ), which I eventually want to move into a String.
let dref = jval.dyn_ref::<ReadableStreamByobReader>();
let byob_reader = dref.unwrap();

{
    let array = Uint8Array::new_with_length((fsize as i32) as u32);

    // the below couple of lines do not create the right "Object" for the
    // "read.." function below.    
    let obj =  Object::new();
    Reflect::set(&obj, &"obj".into(), &array);

    // at runtime this fails and jsvascript reports an error 
    let promise = byob_reader.read_with_array_buffer_view(&obj);
}

The error reported is:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'read' on 'ReadableStreamBYOBReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'ArrayBufferView'.
    at imports.wbg.__wbg_read_57beac96bf2997c2 (the_same_page.js:1675:37)
    at the_same_page-a3170f4289488dc0.wasm.web_sys::features::gen_ReadableStreamByobReader::ReadableStreamByobReader::read_with_array_buffer_view::h19c2a87f659c69a6 (the_same_page_bg.wasm:0x214863e)

This indicates what is in the "Object" argument in incorrect for the "read". There is no ArrayView or similarly named struct in wasm_bindgen and web_sys.
How do I give the read variant the proper input argument? Does this method even work in Rust with wasm_bindgen + web_sys? Should I try a completely different way?

Your method of creating a Object is clearly wrong, you probably want to use the AsRef<Object> implementation i.e. call byob_reader.read_with_array_buffer_view(array.as_ref())

Same as before, a search does find that.

will try - that variant is not listed in the web_sys wasm_bindgen docs :O
https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/

@cafce25. interesting it does't say the Uint8Array.as_ref(). returns an "Object".
and a variant of the reader that takes an  &Uint8Array. as an argument is not listed ( that I saw ) there is a lot of implicit interpretation that has to happen it seems.

@cafce25. It looks like the way it is acting is a Uint8Array IS an implementation of Object but that is not obvious.

@cafce25. Pardon being somewhat new to rust and all the rest of it. I have a hard time navigating all the pieces.  Apparently the "as_ref()" as exposed by many of the web_sys impls seems to be used like the (old!) C++ "type conversion" operator.

"that variant is not listed in the web_sys wasm_bindgen docs" – Yes it is! AsRef<Object> for Uint8Array and also searchable

If you're new to Rust, I recommend you get to know the language first, WASM is definitely not the place to start learning.

@cafce25. well somewhat new to rust (Since January ) - we (I) have built a native "Bevy" app to draw lines, drop images and drag them around delete them, and other UI operations.  Most of the app runs in a browser.  But using the web_sys api to get a utf8 file droped on the app from the desktop is proving to be a bit challenging :)
